# Integral related to binomial coefficient $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{(1+e^{ix})^n}{e^{ixk}}~dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I want to show that
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{(1+e^{ix})^n}{e^{ixk}}~dx={n\choose k}$$
My attempts were very poor, since I'm not an expert in contour integration.I thought that, in order to have factorials on the right, the integral could be reduced to a Beta function, but substituting $t=e^{ix}$ doesn't work because of the bounds $-\pi,\pi$. I am wondering if anyone could give me a shove in the right direction.

Comment: Use binomial formula.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1195163/42969

Comment: [Does this help?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnmHZWW47m8&t=759s)

Comment: Yes thank you @Accelerator

Comment: You're welcome. Note that $e^{ix}$ has a period length of $2\pi$ which is the same length as $\left[-\pi, \pi\right]$. So yes, substituting $t= e^{ix}$ works because of the bounds $-\pi$ and $\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$I=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{(1+e^{ix})^n}{e^{ixk}}\text{d}x$$

Let $z=e^{ix}$
$$I=\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint\frac{(1+z)^n}{z^k}\frac{1}{iz}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{k+1}}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\cdot 2\pi i \cdot Res(z=0)$$

where the contour is unit circle, counter-clockwisely.

$$Res(z=0)=\binom{n}{k}$$

therefore,

$$I=\binom{n}{k}$$

Comment: What is the contour in this case? Also can you provide some details for the step that removes the integral?

Comment: yes, add more details.

Comment: @Zima Since MathFail used $z = e^{ix}$ where $x$ goes from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, I think it's already assumed that the contour is the unit circle traversed in the positive direction.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

> $$\left(1 + e^{\mathrm ix}\right)^n =\sum_{\ell = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{\ell} e^{\mathrm i\ell x}$$

and

> $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{\mathrm imx}\mathrm d x = \begin{cases}2\pi & \text{if $m=0$}\\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Yes it is easy this way, now I see it